# Entity Malformation Exception Error

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, display-suite

When I try to access some specific pages, I get the following errors in my log, one after the other:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ds_field_formatter_view() (line 1233 of /var/www/sites/all/modules/ds/ds.module).

Followed by

> EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type taxonomy_term. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7729 of /var/www/includes/common.inc).

And the page serves the following error:

> Error
>   The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

I had the modules taxonomy and taxonomy manager enabled. I disabled taxonomy manager, but no effect. I wanted to disable taxonomy too, but could not because there was a field with data in it. This has made almost 44 pages of the site with good content in accessible, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The error was happening due to the fact that database records where not removed when a taxonomy term reference field was deleted. The solution was to install [taxonomy orphanage](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_orphanage) module which removes such references.

Comment: To make the taxonomy orphanage module effective, one has to go to `/admin/structure/taxonomy/orphanage` and click "Round up". This can be set to be done by cron, but is not done automatically on module installation.